# wxPython placing form code in discrete .py files (not using pubsub)

Tags: python, wxpython

I am migrating a little Excel/VBA-based application to wxPython/SQLite3, learning the latter as I go. As time goes on I'm finding navigating the code a more and more unwieldy - it's only 880 lines currently, but it's a bit more than I'm used to managing - and so was wondering whether there was a simple solution to putting form code for each form each in discrete .pys.

For example, at the bottom of my current .py, I have the bit that starts the main form:

```
class AuditApp(wx.App):
  def OnInit(self):
    self.aframe = audFrame(None, -1, "Audits Manager")
    self.aframe.Show(True)
    self.SetTopWindow(self.aframe)  # has to be *after* the Show()
    return True

def main():
  app = AuditApp(0)
  app.MainLoop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

That audFrame currently displays a menu and a list:

```
class audFrame(wx.Frame):
  def __init__(self, parent, id, title):    
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title)
    self.scwd = os.getcwd()
    if AppCompiled:
      image = "/home/robyn//dev/Audits/FoggyM.jpg"
    else:
      image = self.scwd + "/FoggyM.jpg"
    self.SetBackgroundStyle(wx.BG_STYLE_CUSTOM)
    self.bg = wx.Bitmap(image)
    self._width, self._height = self.bg.GetSize()
    # Menu Section
    audmbar = wx.MenuBar()
    mfile = wx.Menu()
    medit = wx.Menu()
    mhelp = wx.Menu()
    mfile.Append(101, "Post-Op &Times", "Post-Op Stay in Minutes")
    mfile.Append(102, "&Patient Satisfaction", "Post-discharge telephone interview")
    mfile.AppendSeparator()
    mquit = wx.MenuItem(mfile, 110, "&Quit\tCtrl+Q", "Leave Audits Manager")
    mfile.AppendItem(mquit)
    mhelp.Append(150, "&Help", "Audit Manager Help")
    mhelp.AppendSeparator()
    mhelp.Append(159, "&About AuditsMgr", "About Audits Manager")
    audmbar.Append(mfile, "&Modules")
    audmbar.Append(medit, "&Edit")
    audmbar.Append(mhelp, "&Help")
    # Data
    self.mconn = self.doConnect()
    self.mcurs = self.mconn.cursor()
    # "SELECT patid, anaesthetist, proctype, intvdate FROM interv ORDER BY intvdate"
    self.mcurs.execute("SELECT patid || '  ' || intvdate || '  ' || proctype || '  ' || anaesthetist AS intvlist FROM interv")
    patList = [item[0] for item in self.mcurs.fetchall()]
    # Top
    line01 = wx.StaticLine(self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.LI_HORIZONTAL)
    pnlTop = wx.Panel(self, -1, style=wx.SUNKEN_BORDER|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL)
    BxSzr1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    BxSzr1.Add(pnlTop, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
    self.listBox1 = wx.ListBox(choices=patList, id=160, name='Results', parent=pnlTop, 
                    pos=wx.Point(20, 20), size=wx.Size(450, 300), style=0)
    self.listBox1.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(255, 255, 128))
    #self.listBox1.Bind(wx.EVT_LISTBOX, self.OnListBox1Listbox, id=wxID_FRAME1LISTBOX1)
    btnSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    self.btnFind = wx.Button(self, 180, u"&Find", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0)        
    self.btnClose = wx.Button(self, 181, u"&Close", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0)
    btnSizer.Add(self.btnFind, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
    btnSizer.Add(self.btnClose, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
    # Main Sizer
    MainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    MainSizer.Add(BxSzr1, 14, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)    
    MainSizer.Add(line01, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)    
    MainSizer.Add(btnSizer, 1, wx.ALIGN_RIGHT, 5)        
    """
    ====> MAIN LAYOUT CODE <====
    """
    self.Size = wx.Size(1000, 700)
    self.SetMenuBar(audmbar)
    self.CreateStatusBar()
    self.SetSizer(MainSizer)
    self.Layout()
    self.Centre(wx.BOTH)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.doPOTimes, id = 101)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.doInterv, id = 102)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.onQuit, id = 110)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.onHelp, id = 150)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.onAbout, id = 159)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_ERASE_BACKGROUND, self.OnEraseBackground)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.clkFind, id = 180)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onQuit, id = 181)

  def clkFind(self, event):
  #  findRec = wx.MessageDialog(self, )
  #  self.popForm()
    event.Skip()

  def clkClose(self, event):
    self.curs.close()
    self.conn.close()
    self.Close()

  def doPOTimes(self, event):
    frm = frmTimes(None, -1, "Post-Op Times")
    frm.Show()

  def doInterv(self, event):
    frm = frmIntervw(None, -1, "Post-Discharge Interview")
    frm.Show()

  def doConnect(self):
    conStr = "/home/robyn/data/audits.db"
    return sqlite3.connect(conStr)

  def onHelp(self, event):
    pass
```

The menu brings up other forms and dialogues. It was for those forms that I was wondering if it were possible to place the code in a discrete .py.

I had a look at pubsub, but it seemed overkill - the forms simply did data collection and didn't really need to communicate anything with the main form, at least, that's what I gathered from this [excellent tutorial](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/06/27/wxpython-and-pubsub-a-simple-tutorial/):

> I see a number of questions on the wxPython mailing list or its IRC channel about communicating between frames and most of the time what the developer needs is the PubSub module. The Publisher / Subscriber model is a way to send messages to one or more listeners.

All that seemed a bit more than I needed, unless I misunderstood what the author of the tutorial meant by 'Communicating between two frames'.

I guess what I'm asking is: can code for the same application live in several .py files, where each form would have its own .py file, to be called by the bound method, to sort-of replace that:

```
def dodoInterv(self, event):
    frm = frmIntervw(None, -1, "Post-Discharge Interview")
    frm.Show()
```

with something that will call (import?) a .py instead.
Am I opening a can of worms, here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the example in  the PyPubSub tutorial may seem pointless, it is only to show how to use the module. PyPubSub does come in handy when you need to handle multiple threads running independently of the main thread. It is true though, at least from my experience that any need of PyPubSub can be overcome by passing a reference of one frame to another.

As for your question, yes you can comfortably write the code of a single application on several modules. Just import those modules in the ones where you need them. People do it all the time, otherwise it would be impossible to write the entire code in a single py file.

For the code you have provided, you can write the codes for the classes in different files and simply import the classes to the main .py file.

Say for example `audFrame` is defined in a separate `frame.py` file. You can change your code for the `main.py` file to something like this:

```
import frame

class AuditApp(wx.App):
  def OnInit(self):
    self.aframe = frame.audFrame(None, -1, "Audits Manager")
    self.aframe.Show(True)
    self.SetTopWindow(self.aframe)  # has to be *after* the Show()
    return True

def main():
  app = AuditApp(0)
  app.MainLoop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Comment: Nepix32 made reference to Model View Controller, which I studied. If I understand what you're telling me correctly, user2963623, you and he are basically singing off the same page. IOW: your suggestion regarding the frame is essentially his "View" bit, right? and the same could be done with the methods (Controller) and data (Model). This is a bit different to how I had envisioned it, where each form (data handling, GUI and associated methods) would all live in a separate .py. However doing it this way allows more of a OOP approach rather than re-inventing the wheel with future forms.

Comment: I didn't have the MVC specifically in my mind while writing the answer. MVC or any other form of organisation is purely logical. For my own purposes, I usually write every individual frame class with its event handlers in individual .py files and simply import them wherever I need to make their object. So don't be bothered about any particular framework; just make a sketch of how you want to organize the code and go ahead with it.

Answer (score 0):

This can indeed be a problem with people with a casual programming background coming to do GUI driven programs. What me helped a lot was going through the [ModelViewController tutorial](http://wiki.wxpython.org/ModelViewController) in the wxPython wiki. Even if you would agree to using a MVC pattern, it is hard without knowing the terminology to understand what the talk is all about.

This example shows you in a clear-cut manner what belongs in which part of the MVC pattern and how to write it using python/wxPython.

For your example: You would stuff everything which belongs to data retrieval (sqlite) in its own object. Now comes the tricky part: How to tell the wxPython objects what to do with the model or how to make the model known to them?

Enter the controller: Suppose you want to enter a query argument, do the query and display the result:

- in your view part (would correspond to the GUI part of your audit frame) enter an argument
- Bind to the view part from the controller (e. g. when clicking "Query")
- Use a method in the controller as target for the bound method
- Do the query in the controller method (corresponds roughly to your doConnect)
- at the end of the query controller method update the view with the result from the query

The MVC example is one file, but if you keep things separated, you can put e.g. the view into a separate .py file and import it. The View does not even need to know about sqlite/the model. The connection between model and view is done by the controller, who needs to know about both object.

EDIT: To answer your original question: It is not necessary to use pubsub, in your rather simple example you can use callbacks.

HTH